# How to style dl and another dl so they are on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for an hour but I couldn't find a way to do it.
my problem is those two dl tag couldn't make the same line.

What my expected result is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eblvU.png)

Here's my HTML:

```
       <dl class="dropdown">
            <dt>
                <label style="font-weight:500;">SuperClass</label>

                <a href="#">
                    <input class="hida form-control-sm" style="height:32px; font-weight:400; border:1px solid #d1d3e2;" value="SuperClass Filter" />
                </a>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="mutiSelect">
                    <ul style="height:auto;">
                        @Html.Action("_ClassPartialView")
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>       
        </dl>
        <dl class="dropdown2">
            <dt>
                <label style="font-weight:500;">Status:</label>
                <a href="#">

                    <input class="hida form-control-sm" style="height:32px; font-weight:400; border:1px solid #d1d3e2;" value="Status Filter" />
                </a>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="mutiSelectStatus">
                    <ul style="height:auto;">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="one" onchange="filter()" name="ab" />one</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="two" onchange="filter()" name="ab" />two</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
```

Comment: What does `dl` means?

Answer (score 2):

This might be very quick and dirty but it could work for you.
Add a wrapper around your `dl`'s like in my example with `container` (if you haven't already got one).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container dl {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<dl class="dropdown">
            <dt>
                <label style="font-weight:500;">SuperClass</label>

                <a href="#">
                    <input class="hida form-control-sm" style="height:32px; font-weight:400; border:1px solid #d1d3e2;" value="SuperClass Filter" />
                </a>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="mutiSelect">
                    <ul style="height:auto;">
                        @Html.Action("_ClassPartialView")
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>       
        </dl>
        <dl class="dropdown2">
            <dt>
                <label style="font-weight:500;">Status:</label>
                <a href="#">

                    <input class="hida form-control-sm" style="height:32px; font-weight:400; border:1px solid #d1d3e2;" value="Status Filter" />
                </a>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <div class="mutiSelectStatus">
                    <ul style="height:auto;">
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="one" onchange="filter()" name="ab" />one</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="two" onchange="filter()" name="ab" />two</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only piece of content you want to display, but if so you could simply give give these 2 `dl`'s a parent div and give it the style of `display: flex;`.

Because im not sure what the final result has to be (full table with a lot of extra data or just this), it's a little hard to give you proper feedback.

Comment: ya ... I think changing the display property will fix this. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)